# Follow/following system Django - how to check if user is already following

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Trying to build a follow/following system with `Django`.  The model seems to be working but I'm running into issues trying to perform an "already-following" check in my `view`.

Here is the view:

```
class FollowView(View):
    model = UserRelationships

    def get(self, request, username=None):
        user = self.request.user
        viewed_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if user not in viewed_user.followers.all():
            UserRelationships.objects.create(user_id=user, following_user_id=viewed_user)
        data = {}
        return HttpResponse(data)
```

At this point, a new object gets created each time I hit the "Follow" button regardless if the user is already following.

Here is the `UserRelationships` `model`:

```
class UserRelationships(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="following")
    following_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followers")

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And the two relevant URLs (base and specific app):

```
path('accounts/<username>/', include('accounts.urls'))
```

```
path('follow/', FollowView.as_view(), name='follow')
```

And then I pass in the current user's username via a template tag for the `HTML` button.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add `print(user)` and `print(viewed_user.followers.all())` before the condition. What does it show?

Comment: This is what I got for `print(user)`: `tsmith41094` (a username).  And then I got a `QuerySet` for `print(viewed_user.followers.all())`: `<QuerySet [<UserRelationships: UserRelationships object (5)>]>`  ---- so do I need to access it differently?